# Print last month name in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Can anyone please help me in getting last month name in MySQL.

I am getting the current month name using the query

```
date_format(now(),'%M'),
```

But I am not able to print the last month name by altering this statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DATE_SUB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) to subtract an [interval](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) of 1 month from NOW() :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%M');
```